# piecewise regression into a for loop

Tags: regression, piecewise-linear

I´m trying get a piecewise regression.

```
for(i in 1:length(Velocidad)){
  if(Velocidad[i]< vmin)
    pred.pot[i]<<-0
  if(Velocidad[i]>vmin && Velocidad[i]< vmax)
    pred.pot[i]<<-predict(reg)
  if(Velocidad[i]< vmax)
    pred.pot[i]<<-2000
}
```

Warning: number of items to replace is not a multiple of    replacement length

Any idea as to how predict between the limits?

** I can't use the explicit equation because its order depends on other function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use vector arithmetic:

```
pred.pot <- (Velocidad < vmin) * 0 +
            (Velocidad >= vmin & Velocidad <= vmax) * predict(reg) +
            (Velocidad < vmin) * 2000
```

or a vectorized `ifelse`

```
pred.pot <- ifelse(Velocidad < vmin, 0,
                ifelse(Velocidad >= vmin & Velocidad <= vmax,  predict(reg),
                    2000))
```

Don't loop over atomic vectors in R unless you really need to (though lists are another thing entirely).  Don't use `<<-` unless you really need to.  If you're ever wondering if you really need to do either of these things, you don't need to.

Finally, always use brackets, even in single line `if` statements.

Comment: If you wondering why you should always use brackets, this bug in apple's ssl code is an exemplar of why omitting them is an error: https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/

Comment: Thank you for your advices but now i get this warning:

In (Velocidad >= vmin & Velocidad <= vmax) * predict(reg) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: That error is pretty clear to me.  It means the length of the `Velcidad` vector is not the same as the `predict(reg)` vector.  You'll have to fix that yourself, as you did not provide context for what these vectors are.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've already found my fail and it's solved.